# How can I increment a value in a java method according to the listed rules

Tags: java, performance, loops, methods

I am writing a grow method for a Fly class grow takes an int variable which is supposed to increase the flies mass and affect its speed according to these rules.

-If mass is less than 20: increases speed by 1 for every mass the Fly grows until it reaches 20 mass.
-If the mass is 20 or more: decreases speed by 0.5 for each mass unit added over 20.

I am not allowed to import any external classes or packages

default mass is set to 5
default speed is set to 10

This is my code:

```
public void grow(int mass)
{   
    this.mass += mass;//total mass
    if(this.mass < 20) 
    {
        speed+=mass;
    }
    else if(this.mass >= 20) 
            {       
        speed -= ((this.mass-20)/2);
        if(speed <=0)
            speed =0; //so that speed isnt set to a negative number
    }
    
}
```

if i enter a value into mass that causes total mass to go above 20 speed decreases without increasing
example:

mass =5 speed = 10
30 is added

speed = 16
mass = 35  //correct code output

speed = 2.5
mass = 35 //my code output

Comment: Call your parameter `massAdded` instead of `mass`, that would be clearer, but basically you have to realise that both increases and decreases in speed can happen in a single call to `grow`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

- use a loop to control how masses are added. Loop from `0 to mass` exclusive.
- Inside the loop

  - add 1 to mass for each iteration
  - if mass < 20, increase speed by 1
  - else decrease speed by .5

Comment: It worked, I can't upvote since I need 15 rep but I appreciate the help

Comment: @YesinQ  But you can accept the answer,  Just click the `check` icon to the left of the answer.